# How to install pass (password store) on EC2?

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2

When I `docker login` on an ec2 Linux machine I get:

```
WARNING! Your password will be stored unencrypted in /root/.docker/config.json.
Configure a credential helper to remove this warning. See
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/#credentials-store
```

Per the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/#default-behavior), installing [pass](https://www.passwordstore.org) will make this warning go away.

When I run `yum install pass` on the e2c instance, yum complains `No package pass available.` I tried `sudo amazon-linux-extras install epel` prior to looking up the package but it did not help.

How can I install `pass` on e2c's Amazon Linux 2 AMI instances?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, *pass* was retired from epel 7
(https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1639806)

The latest *pass* requires *Git* version >= 1.8.5
and *tree* version >= 1.7.0 (in my ec2 machine *tree* is at version 1.6.0).

Of course, you can always install all the requirements by hand: https://git.zx2c4.com/password-store/tree/README

There has been some discussion about this (i.e., support *centos* 7) in the pass list, but not the outcome yet:
https://lists.zx2c4.com/pipermail/password-store/2019-July/003686.html

https://lists.zx2c4.com/pipermail/password-store/2019-July/003717.html

Answer (score 0):

Try to install with pip:

```
pip install pass
```

Comment: pass is not a Python application and it is not available on PyPI.